# Verifying JWT generated by Node in Laravel

Tags: node.js, laravel, jwt

I'm generating a token on our auth server (Node.js) in [node-jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) that will be passed to an API (PHP Laravel) and verified by [tymondesigns/jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth).

- A token generated by tymondesigns/jwt-auth will be verified successfully by
  its own verify function, node-jsonwebtoken and [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/).
- A token generated by node-jsonwebtoken will be verified successfully by its own verify function, [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/), **but not tymondesigns/jwt-auth**.

On the Laravel server, i get the following error when I try to verify a token generated by node-jsonwebtoken:

```
TokenInvalidException in NamshiAdapter.php line 71:
Token Signature could not be verified.
```

The payloads look identical when I look at them over at [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/). I have even tried to generate the exact same token on the Node server by passing the same iat,sub,iss,exp,nbf and jti as generated by a working token, but tymondesigns/jwt-auth still won't accept it.

Is there anything else that could be causing this, but isn't visible in the decoded information? I'm also not 100% sure how jti works. Maybe there is something preventing this from working about that?

*node-jsonwebtoken (7.1.9), tymon/jwt-auth (0.5.9), namshi/jose (5.0.2)*

Answer (score 2):

The last version of the `namshi/jose` library is 7.0.
There is also a known bugs for all `ESxxx` algorithms.

If you cannot verify signatures using that library, you could try with another one.
I developed [a library](https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/jose) that supports all features described in the RFCs related to the JWT, including encryption support.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is, as mentioned by Spomky aswell, a bug in **namshi/jose** related to the `iss` claim. It is resolved in `7.0` which is used by **tymon/jwt-auth** `1.0.0-alpha.2`. However, since there currently isn't a documented way to install 1.0.0-alpha.2, we probably have to wait for a stable release.

Until then, since the problem and the bug is related to the `iss` claim, removing the `iss` requirement from `required_claims` and generating the tokens without it solves the problem temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a url inside the payload. PHP escapes slashes by default when encoding to JSON, while Node.js doesn't. When the verification JWT gets generated in PHP (with those extra backslashes) of course the final hashes won't match since the payload is just different. Solution is to use the JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES flag when converting to JSON inside your JWT library, I was using https://github.com/namshi/jose so I created a simple class like this one:

```
use Namshi\JOSE\SimpleJWS;

class SimpleJWSWithEncodeOptions extends SimpleJWS
{
    protected static $encodeOptions = 0;

    public static function setEncodeOptions($options)
    {
        self::$encodeOptions = $options;
    }

    /**
     * Generates the signed input for the current JWT.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function generateSigninInput()
    {
        $base64payload = $this->encoder->encode(json_encode($this->getPayload(), self::$encodeOptions));
        $base64header  = $this->encoder->encode(json_encode($this->getHeader(), self::$encodeOptions));

        return sprintf("%s.%s", $base64header, $base64payload);
    }
}
```

Then it could be used like:

```
SimpleJWSWithEncodeOptions::setEncodeOptions(JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
$jws = SimpleJWSWithEncodeOptions::load($token);
$jws->verify($key);
$data = $jws->getPayload();
```

This problem was very specific to my payload content but it could help someone